# IOS Swift Listing Files in an URL

Tags: ios, swift, apache, openstack

I am new at IOS - Swift language. I am just trying to pass this android code below that includes org.apache.ivy.util.url.ApacheURLLister module. Is there any way for Swift to get a list of files and folders in an Url?
(example; 1.jpg , dot.jpg in 'www.example.com/images/')

```
public static ArrayList<URL> getFileList(URL url1) {
    ArrayList<URL> serverDir = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ApacheURLLister lister1 = new ApacheURLLister();
        serverDir.addAll(lister1.listAll(url1));
        System.out.println(serverDir);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("getFileList", "Error listing url " + url);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return serverDir;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by using Alamofire;

```
func getFileList(url: String,files_downloaded: Bool, got_xmls_on_sd_card: Bool, _directory: NSString,building_folder: NSURL) {
        Alamofire.request(.GET, url)
            .responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.error == nil else {
                    print("Error on request getFileList()")
                    print(response.result.error)
                    return
                }

                if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value {
                    let results = JSON(value)
                    var fileList : [String] = []
                    for i in 0..<results.count {
                        //TODO fill fileList with urls
                    }

                    //TODO return fileList
                }
        }
    }
```